# Is $S_1\cap S_2$ and $S_1\setminus S_2$ always linearly dependent if $S_1$ and $S_2$ are linearly dependent subsets of vector space $V$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $S_1$ and $S_2$ be linearly dependent subsets of vector space $V$, are $S_1\cap S_2$ and $S_1\setminus S_2$ always linearly dependent?

The counterexample for the first one I can think of is $S_1=\{(1,0),(0,1), (1,1)\}$ and $S_2=\{(1,0),(0,1), (0,0)\}$.

The counterexample for the second one I can think of is $S_1=\{(1,0),(0,1), (1,1)\}$ and $S_2=\{(1,1)\}$.

But I am not sure if I'm correct?

Comment: Is the intersection and intersection of generated spaces or just a regular ol' set intersection?

Comment: Your second counterexample $S_2$ is wrong since you can't have a single vector be linearly dependent (unless that is the 0 vector). That said you are close to correct, just pick bigger sets of vectors for $S_1$ and $S_2$

Comment: Is adding $(2, 0)$ the same thing as adding $(1, 0)$ as they are scalar multiple of each other?

Answer (score 1):

If $S_1$ and $S_2$ are dependent, neither $S_1 \cap S_2$ nor $S_1 \setminus S_2$ need to be dependent.

If $S_1 \cap S_2 = \emptyset$, then $S_1 \cap S_2$ is independent if you use the convention that $\emptyset$ is independent.

If $S_1 \cap S_2$ contains a single vector $v \ne 0$, then $S_1 \cap S_2$ is independent. In particular, a set $(v)$ containing one vector is linearly independent if and only if $v \ne 0$.

If $S_1 \cap S_2$ contains a set of vectors $(v_1,\ldots,v_k)$, then $S_1 \cap S_2$ can be independent if $S_1 \cap S_2$ is a proper subset of $S_1$ and $S_2$.

Let $S_1=(v_1,\ldots,v_k)$ be a dependent set of vectors. Then $S_1$ can be made into a linearly independent set $S_1^\prime$ obtained by deleting all the vectors $v_j$ such that $v_j \in \text{span}(S_1) \setminus (v_j)$.
The set $S_1 \setminus S_2$ is independent if $S_1 \setminus S_2 = S_1^\prime$. In other words, $S_1 \setminus S_2$ is independent if $S_2$ is a dependent list containing all the vectors deleted from $S_1$ to obtain $S_1^\prime$.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.

Take any linearly independent set $A$, and let one of the elements be $a$. Then $A=(A\cup\{0\})\cap (A\cup 2a)$, and both of the sets we are intersecting are linearly dependent.

For the other example notice $A=(A\cup\{0\})\setminus\{0\}$

---

We assume the field is not of characteristic $2$ in the first example.